# Docker Container is exited with status code 255

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
        jenkins:
                container_name: jenkins     
                image: jenkins/jenkins 
                ports: 
                        - "8080:8080"
                volumes: 
                        - "$PWD/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home"
                networks:
                        - net
        remote_host:
                container_name: remote-host
                image: remote-host
                build: 
                        context: ubuntu_container
                networks:
                        - net
networks:
        net:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash remote_user && \
    echo  'remote_user:<password>' | chpasswd && \
    mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh && \ 
    chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh

COPY remote-key.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN chown remote_user:remote_user -R /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 600 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN ssh-keygen -A


CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Output of $ docker-compose build

```
Building remote_host
Step 1/7 : FROM ubuntu:20.04
 ---> 74435f89ab78
Step 2/7 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dfaef48ff3df
Step 3/7 : RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash remote_user &&     echo  'remote_user:root123' | chpasswd &&   mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh &&     chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 978387042c0f
Step 4/7 : COPY remote-key.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d5bc890cc4c1
Step 5/7 : RUN chown remote_user:remote_user -R /home/remote_user/.ssh &&   chmod 600 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0a99e09c02aa
Step 6/7 : RUN ssh-keygen -A
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8ed7cac699d5
Step 7/7 : CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D
 ---> Running in de3b02ee7c10
Removing intermediate container de3b02ee7c10
 ---> 64eee00b5a0f
Successfully built 64eee00b5a0f
Successfully tagged remote-host:latest
```

Output of $ docker-compose up -d

```
Recreating remote-host ... done
```

output of $ docker ps -a

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                               NAMES
2cb7f0c7f6b0        remote-host         "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb…"   13 seconds ago      Exited (255) 9 seconds ago                                         remote-host
```

My container had been build and created successfully still its getting exited with status code 255. Could you please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

Use your docker-compose file like this in order to map your host docker.sock:

```
version: '3'
services:
    jenkins:
            container_name: jenkins     
            image: jenkins/jenkins 
            privileged: true
            ports: 
               - "8080:8080"
            volumes: 
               - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
               - "$PWD/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home"
            networks:
               - net
    remote_host:
            container_name: remote-host
            image: remote-host
            build: 
                context: ubuntu_container
            networks:
                - net
networks:
    net:
```

Comment: Thank you MikZuit, I tried solution suggested by you still facing same issue.Container is getting terminated with 255 status code

Answer (score 1):

By adding the port details in docker-composer.yml file, I am able to start the container. So I added line under remote_host: saying ports: "8081:8081". Or we can do it using EXPOSE PORT 22 as sshd uses 22 as default port